# I want my brother and mother to move to Australia

Tags: visas, australia

please if you could guide me out.

German citizen and been almost 3 years in Aus. I've received last year my partner visa ( I have an Australian wife and 2 kids) .

I want to bring my brother and mother to live with me and study. He is 9 years old and my mother is 52. Both german citizen

**What visa would they need to be eligible to stay and live with me ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions about immigrant visas should go to http://expatriates.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: thank you, i've posted before a immigrational post and assumed it was ok @NateEldredge